# How do I prevent auto-linkification in BitBucket commit comments?

Tags: links, markdown, bitbucket

BitBucket auto-linkifies some text in your comment comments, like issue numbers after the word "issue" and what it thinks are changest identifiers/hashes.

Now, I'm writing this table which has a column whose contents is a number of a certain length. For some reason, BitBucket auto-linkifies these numbers. [Example issue page](https://bitbucket.org/eyalroz/db-kernel-testbench/issues/149) (scroll down to the table of results)

Is there anything I can do to tell BitBucket to just leave these numbers alone?

I was thinking there should probably be some escaping mechanism, but I figure out what that might be.